# MediaQuery inconsistent on different phones

Tags: flutter, responsive

i have a scaffold that keeps giving me overflow errors when i test on different phones. i only used `mediaquery.of(context).size.height` once in the code and i get overflow error 0f 40.392 and it makes no sense since i never used decimals when declaring heights

```
    Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      appBar: PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(50),
        child: AppBar(
          elevation: 0,
          iconTheme: const IconThemeData(color: Colors.blue),
          backgroundColor: mode.background1,
          actions: actionList(),
        ),
      ),
      body: Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 104,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
                //overflow error exists right here
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 107,
                child: getWid(_selectedindex)),
            Container(
              height: 3,
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  mydivider(0),
                  mydivider(1),
                  mydivider(2),
                  mydivider(3),
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: Theme(
        data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
            brightness: Brightness.dark,
            canvasColor: mode.canvasColor,
            primaryColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 45, 124, 243),
            textTheme: Theme.of(context)
                .textTheme
                .copyWith(bodySmall: const TextStyle(color: Colors.grey))),
        child: SizedBox(
          height: 54,
          child: BottomNavigationBar(
              onTap: (int index) {
                setState(() {
                  _selectedindex = index;
                });
              },
              currentIndex: _selectedindex,
              type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
              selectedItemColor: Colors.blue,
              unselectedItemColor: Colors.grey,
              items: const [
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.list),
                  label: 'List',
                ),
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.local_grocery_store),
                  label: 'Checkout',
                ),
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.history),
                  label: 'Transactions',
                ),
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.settings_outlined),
                  label: 'Settings',
                )
              ]),
        ),
      ),
    )
```

its clear i gave all widgets height. i think the only logical explanation is an error from building the widgets on this particular phone but i don't know how to go about it. plus i've tested many applications on said phone before.
I appreciate your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `MediaQuery` use `LayoutBuilder` for building UI.

```dart
return Scaffold(
  body: LayoutBuilder(
    builder: (context, constraints) {
      final width = constraints.maxWidth;

      return Text("");
    },
  ),
);
```

More about [LayoutBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/LayoutBuilder-class.html) and [adaptive-responsive](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/layout/adaptive-responsive).

Answer (score 2):

You may need to wrap your body in SafeArea widget. That's the first issue that comes to mind if your layout works on some phones and does not work on other models.

Answer (score 0):

One very important thing to mention: different phones may have 1.text scaling and 2.display scaling. For example people with bad vision may use the largest text and that may cause an issue in your case.[image]

You can use  double textScale = MediaQuery.of(context).textScaleFactor;

And depending on that change your styles. Or you can ignore scaling and all users will see the same.